# MVC5 EditorTemplates for DataTypes Cached Locally?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, caching, razor, editortemplates

I have a Datatype that I've made EditorTemplates for.

Double?

//Example of Double

```
@model Double?

@{
    string name, id;

    if (ViewData.ModelMetadata.ContainerType.Name.Contains("ViewModel"))
    {
        name = ViewData.ModelMetadata.PropertyName;
        id = ViewData.ModelMetadata.PropertyName;
    }
    else
    {
        name = ViewData.ModelMetadata.ContainerType.Name + "." + ViewData.ModelMetadata.PropertyNam
        id = ViewData.ModelMetadata.ContainerType.Name + "_" + ViewData.ModelMetadata.PropertyName;
    }

}

<div class="input-group">
    <span class="input-group-addon" style="background-color:beige">$</span>
    <input type="number" value="@Model" min="0" step="0.01" data-number-to-fixed="2" data-number-stepfactor="100" class="form-control currency" style="width:247px" id="@id" name="@name" />
</div>
```

I have two areas in the website, at first I tried putting to a different version of the Editor template in each Shared folder. I'm unable to hit the break point in either Area.

> A copy of Double.cshtml was found in App_Web_dsfaso.dll.. current
>   source code different

But when I deploy on the server everything works correctly. This has made testing and developing in my local environment more difficult.

Has anyone experiences this issue? Any suggestions?